# KoaJs Custom ErrorHandler middleware now working

Tags: node.js, error-handling, koa, koa.js

I want to create an errorHandler middleware for my app. I used KoaJs for my web application and my error basic handler function like that:

error-handler.ts:

```
import { Context } from "koa";

export const errorHandler : any = (err : Error, ctx : Context ) =>{

    console.log("Something went wrong") ====>>> Its Work
    ctx.status = 403. ========>>>> Not work
    ctx.body = "asdasd" =========>>>> Not work

}
```

And my endpoint which used error handler like that:

```
public static async helloWorld(ctx: BaseContext): Promise<void> {
    throw new Error ('Error Here');
}
```

And my app.js like that:

```
import Koa from "koa";
import { errorHandler }  from './middleware/error-handler';
...
app.use(errorHandler)
...
```

And When I send request to endpoint I getting an error like that :

[image]

Why Im getting this error? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your error handler does not work, because you are not catching the error.

**Your code works as follows:**

As you have a `use(errorHandler)` and in the error handler no `await next()`, your complete error handler is executed first (no matter if there is an error or not). Then your `helloWorld` function is executed. And as there is an uncatched error, Koa does reply a 404 not found to the client.

**How it should be:**

Your errorHandler should have a `await next()`, then afterwards it needs to check if there is an error. If yes, then this needs to be captured and then you can specify status code and resulting body.

**Possible solution:**

I guess your errorHandler should look more like this:

```
export const errorHandler : any = async (ctx : Context, next ) =>{
    try {
      await next();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Something went wrong");
      ctx.status = 403;
      ctx.body = err;
    }
}
```